# Expo eject how to specify os

Tags: react-native, expo

i'm using expo eject and my problem here is that it didn't even generate the ios folder, i only get android folder

but i neet it to generate both android and ios folder and i don't know how to specify that.

here is my app.json code :

```
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier" : "com.Belmwassel.IOS"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
```

and here is the result of my command

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to be running MacOS for it to generate the iOS folder. Personally I think it should generate it anyways even if I can't do anything with it (I'm on Windows) but it's also possible there are some technical limitations.